# Buffer Overflow: NOP sled not working

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, buffer-overflow

Hey I'm trying to do a buffer overflow on a basic C program, the shellcode i'm using in gdb is in the form

NOP sled then msfvenom payload to connect back to my own machine, finally a memory address of somewhere in the NOP sled.

When running gdb, before the shellcode is executed I can see that the NOP instructions start at 0x7fffffffe010 which is the address I have at the end of the shellcode. After the shellcode is executed the rip register is at 0x7fffffffe010 however it gives me the warning:

```
 Cannot insert breakpoint 0.
 Cannot access memory at address 0x40000

 0x00007fffffffe010 in ?? ()
```

I thought the rip would now read the NOP's and go into the payload to connect back to my machine I can't understand why it's not working.

Comment: It may very well be working. What you are seeing is just gdb error, not program error. Let it continue.

Comment: Thanks for the help but was missing certain options when compiling!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!

I needed to compile the c with no stack protection and with an executable stack, i.e:

`gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o output file.c`